# How do I hide a table row conditionally in HTML/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Newbie to StackOverflow - so thanks to all who might help.

An application we use to deliver quotes online to our customers outputs HTML that I can mostly customize. There is a type of row that is output that I'd like to suppress in the HTML conditionally.

The HTML looks like:

```
            <tr class="row-heading">
                <td colspan="3" class="col-description">
                    P=
                </td>
                <td class="col-picture">

                </td>
                <td class="col-unit-price">
                </td>
                <td class="col-extended-price">
                </td>
            </tr>
```

When the data within the class of "col-description" is P= then i'd like to suppress the entire table row with the class of row-heading.

I am great fiddling with HTML and CSS, but JavaScript not so much. I did a bit of research before posting, and I saw something about needing to .hide() but I can't figure out how to formulate this type of JavaScript.

Also, where within the HTML rendered page does this JavaScript need to live? At the beginning? At the end? In a  block?

Thanks in advance for help and advice!

Comment: Add classes through the application, then check for them with Javascript. Use the javascript `element.style.display = "none"`

Comment: This kind of question is not what we want on Stackoverflow. Try out some stuff first, if it doesn't work, try to fix it, and if you can't, come here with your problem and the solutions you tried. Just expecting us to solve your problems without trying to do so yourself is not in the spirit of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would add your JavaScript inside a `<script>` after the whole html so that it is applied when html is loaded.

Now your task has two parts: find all the elements to hide and hide them. Since you tagged this with jQuery I suppose that using jQuery is ok. To find cells with `P=`, you may use this custom `:contains` selector:

```
var $cells = jQuery('td:contains("P=")');
```

To get the rows, you have to use the `parent()` method:

```
var $rows = jQuery('td:contains("P=")').parent();
```

Finally, you want to hide them, so hide them:

```
jQuery('td:contains("P=")').parent().hide();
```

The latter line is what you want, as far as I understand your question.

But as guys have mentioned, this kind of questions is not encouraged here. You should rather try to learn basics using other sources and ask here if you have specific questions of non-basic level.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will try and make this work.

Comment: Genius! Thank you so much for your help - this worked perfectly! One line of code and if I tell you how long I've wanted to implement this and how much time I've spent researching instead of just asking :) THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to check for some condition on when you want to hide something. If you do add the `:hidden` or even have a css class you make `.hide` and do `display:none;`. Given that you don't want to show it add a class `.addClass('hide')`

This is just a thought, there are so many things you could do, If I were you I would toy around with `display:none` and use `.addClass` and `.removeClass`

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar need and was able to accomplish this using:

List("",
variable1,
variable2,
etc
)

The variables are either blank or the html tags for the tables rows if not blank

This worked beautifully with no jQuery or JavaScript

Comment: try putting your code in code snippets, so they appear like code, you can highlight your text code, then click on the code button with icon `{ }`, it will indent your text and render them as code, or you can indent the text yourself. Take a look at [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page it contains markdown basics to better showcase your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the set the style to  display:none.